# Keyboard, orientation, and UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextview

I've got a UITextview that covers the entire screen. To compensate for the keyboard I added this handler:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
    // Resize for the stupid keyboard
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    CGRect rect = _textView.frame;
    rect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    _textView.frame = rect;

    CGPoint p = [_textView contentOffset];
    [_textView setContentOffset:p animated:NO];
    [_textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([_textView.text length], 0)];
}
```

This works dandy in portrait mode, but the view completely disapears in landscape mode. Is there a more elegant solution for dealing with this? I read apples [keyboard management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) documentation, but it doesn't have much to offer  for orientation issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, my unfortunate solution is this

```
UIInterfaceOrientation o = [self interfaceOrientation];
if(o == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || o == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
    rect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
}else if(o == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || o == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    rect.size.height -= kbSize.width;
}
```

Which i suppose is the only way to address this. I'd still love an elegant solution though :)